# C# Static Variable forgets value

Tags: c#

It sounds a little weird, but I've got some code (which actually is a plugin for MS Blend) that runs perfect in unit testing, but is not working within Blend.

The code is the following.

```
    private static volatile QWGUIRepository s_instance;

    public static void Initialize(IUnityContainer container, string themeuri)
    {
        lock (s_lock)
        {
            s_instance = new QWGUIRepository();
            QWRepository.Initialize(container);
        }
    }
```

In the debugger (after attaching it to Blend), I can see that s_instance gets initialized with a value (is not null afterwards), however as soon as I get out of the method "s_instance" will forget it's value and will be null.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Andreas

Comment: I would say that blend is probably disposing of your plugin assembly while it is not in use.

Answer (score 7):

Two guesses:

1) You're reading in a different `AppDomain` than you're writing in. Static variables are scoped by `AppDomain`. If you look at `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` in the debugger during Initialize and then when you're trying to read it, does it look like they're the same domain?

2) You've actually declared s_instance to be a local variable in Initialize, and aren't touching the static variable. Hopefully that's not the case, but you never know...

Answer (score 4):

I don't know anything about Blend, so this is a wild guess. Does Blend start the plugins in separate AppDomains? You can check that in the debug location toolbar in Visual Studio. That could explain it...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for suggestions. Unfortunately (as usual) it was personal stupidity... 
The answer is - make sure you only use strong-named assemblies.

Andreas